# $.getJSON does not work across domain with me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

the following code does not work with me:

```
$.getJSON(url,
         function (data) {
             if (data.results[0]) {
                 alert('hi');

                 $.each(data["Rows"], function (i, el) {
                     $("#target").append("<a href=\"" + el[1] + "\">" + el[2] + "</a><br />");
                 })

                 //container.html(data);
             } else {
                 var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the data.</p>';
                 container.html(errormsg);
             }
         });
```

And here is the url that I pass: http://www.somedomain.com/page.aspx?sid=6BB5B614-4C43-45DF-BA7D-47A71F0753EF&jsoncallback=?
And here is the JSON that returned back

```
{"Columns":["id","Article_Url","Article_Title","date","num"],
 "Rows":[
   ["5bb93b83-d129-4ca9-8999-ed54910b824d","97.74.67.146/test.html","test","\/Date(1316189236173)\/",25],
   ["82d62b61-d96b-489a-ae91-008b897db553","97.74.67.146/testx.html?xx=x","test","\/Date(1316256259490)\/",11],
   ["97aaf346-1146-429e-bc5a-fcfa4b2d934b","97.74.67.146/testx.html","test","\/Date(1316255702510)\/",4],
   ["2fea1222-e254-4db9-a68e-5129a0d87e8e","97.74.67.146/qn_news_story_s.asp?storyid=1093442005","Oman invests USD3.8b in constructing dry dock","\/Date(1316188504010)\/",2],
   ["82fe900d-eefe-4540-87a4-1fe6057234a7","http://www.menafn.com/qn_news_story.asp?StoryId={83510500-a24b-4f87-9bf1-3985134ee4b6}","Title 1","\/Date(1315411910897)\/",1],
   ["217f8e33-8723-4de3-9afc-438d7172f90e","http://www.menafn.com/qn_news_story_s.asp?StoryId=1093437815&src=MOEN","Title 1","\/Date(1315411969900)\/",1]
 ]
}
```

What Im doing wrong?!

Comment: Does the server handle the parameter `jaconcallback=someFunctionName`? The response should be something like `someFunctionName({"Columns":....});`

Comment: Yes it handles the parameter jaconcallback=someFunctionName

Comment: @Cassini: but in your example-url, you're not giving a function-name as callback

Comment: This is a JSONP so the parameter should be like this jaconcallback=? so the browser will generate this tocken automatically and in the server it reads this token (let suppose it xyz) and create the JSONP like this xyz({"Columnd":...}), is that true or I misunderstand how JSONP works?!

Comment: @Cassini, there is probably a global `xyz` function created on the fly. Open the console, watch the network traffic, and insure you have the xyz(...) wrapping the JSON in the response. If there is no call, don't be shy and debug the  `getJSON` function to know why there is no call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is just like any other [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)-request affected by the [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) wich forbids doing cross-domain ajax-requests.

you can work around this doing [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

**EDIT:**
i just read [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) should do an automatic fallback to jsonp if the URL contains a `callback`-parameter:

> **JSONP**
>
> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by
>   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the
>   discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

since you're having a `jsoncallback`-parameter this all might work - but the resonse you posted doesn't use this callback-function (maybe because you're just giving `?` as callback-name) so this might be the whole problem: post a functionname as callback and implement that function on your side.